# Is there a method to populate each row from a csv file into different text files?

Tags: csv, go

I want to take the following records from this CSV file and generate text files with one record in each text file, using Go.

[image: CSV File:]

Output:

Test1.txt

[image: Test1.txt]

Test2.txt

[image: Test2.txt]

Comment: Take a look at the `encoding/csv` package. If you encounter a specific problem, come back and edit your question (or post a new one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("in.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(file)
    fileIndex := 1
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        err := ioutil.WriteFile(
            fmt.Sprintf("Test%d.txt", fileIndex),
            strings.Join(record, " "),
            0755,
        )

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fileIndex++
    }
}
```

Comment: strings.Join(record, " ") throws a type mismatch?

Comment: whoops, `[]byte(strings.Join(record, " "))`

Comment: Thanks @maxm, worked perfectly.